# deployment build for next Js failed

Tags: heroku, deployment, gitlab, next.js

I have a problem when I want to deploy my next js source code on heroku.
During the build process, I have this error

```
Failed to compile.
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/application' in '/tmp/build_4b987283/src/pages'
> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
```

I tried to change folder name, files name. Sometimes it's another folder